# Unwanted Duplicates of ttyACM0 USB ACM Device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ros

Im trying to run the rosserial client on my computer but its having some trouble detecting the USB port. How do I delete so many entries of the same USB port?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just grepping the results of `dmesg`. This doesn't mean that every line there is a duplicate USB device, just that a usb driver is saying something about that *one* device. If you actually want to list connected USB devices you should use `lsusb`